# asp.net int? when in debug being converted to Hex problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

when I debug the values of variables set to an int?are being converted to hex values.
Does anyone know how to prevent the conversion from occuring?

thanks,
Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed this by running in and setting breakpoint and adding the variable to quick watch.
Then right click on the value header and uncheck Hexadecimal Display.

see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/4d205bc7-f04c-4489-9bf6-6a67bda1152c